# Labelling of an axis in plotly by latex

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to label an axis with the help of plotly. Unfortunately, it's not working, not even the official source is working: https://plot.ly/r/figure-labels/

I changed it to:

```
library(plotly)
f <- list(
  family = "Courier New, monospace",
  size = 18,
  color = "#000000"
)
x <- list(
  title = "$\\U_{bias}}$",
  titlefont = f
)
y <- list(
  title = "M / a.u.",
  titlefont = f
)

plot_ly(APDv2, x = ~Bias_voltage, y = ~Slope,
        color = ~Temperature, 
        type = 'scatter', 
        mode = 'markers') %>%
        layout(xaxis=x, yaxis=y)
```

but all I get is the literal expression of x: `$\\U_{bias}$`.
What am I doing wrong?

edit: My package version of plotly is `4.7.1`

Comment: Labeled as 'currently broken': https://plot.ly/r/LaTeX/#latex-typesetting

Comment: Ah, even an obvious information. Didn't recognize it. Thank you! Unfortunately, it seems to be broken for over two years now.